# Android speech recognition pass data back to Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

im really stuck right now and im quite new to Xamarin.
I use Xamarin Forms to develop an App with speech recognition.

I created just a simple UI with a button and an entry-box.

Working:

- Press button and show popup with speech recognition
- read the spoken words into a var

Not Working:

- pass the data back to the Xamarin Forms UI (entry)

StartPage.xaml.cs:

```
    private void BtnRecord_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WaitForSpeechToText();
    } 

    private async void WaitForSpeechToText()
    {
        EntrySpeech.Text = await DependencyService.Get<Listener.ISpeechToText>().SpeechToTextAsync();
    }
```

ISpeechToText.cs:

```
public interface ISpeechToText
{
    Task<string> SpeechToTextAsync();
}
```

to call native code.

SpeechToText_Android.cs:

```
    public class SpeechToText_Android : ISpeechToText
    {
    private const int VOICE = 10;

    public SpeechToText_Android() { }

    public Task<string> SpeechToTextAsync()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        try
        {
            var voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPrompt, "Sprechen Sie jetzt");
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 15000);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, Java.Util.Locale.Default);

            try
            {
                ((Activity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(voiceIntent, VOICE);

            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException a)
            {
                tcs.SetResult("Device doesn't support speech to text");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultVal, Intent data)
    {  
        if (requestCode == VOICE)
        {
            if (resultVal == Result.Ok)
            {
                var matches = data.GetStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraResults);
                if (matches.Count != 0)
                {
                    string textInput = matches[0].ToString();
                    if (textInput.Length > 500)
                        textInput = textInput.Substring(0, 500);
                }
                // RETURN 
            }
        }
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultVal, data);
    }
```

First i thought that i can pass the result with

```
return tcs.Task;
```

back to the ui, but then i noticed that this return is happening when
the pop up of the speech recognition has finished to render. At this moment there was not a single word spoken.

The spoken words are in the string "textInput" in the OnActivityResult function,
but how can i pass this string back to the Xamarin.Forms UI?

Thanks guys !

Comment: SpeechToTextAsync needs to be marked with the async keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an `AutoResetEvent` to pause the return until the `OnActivityResult` is called, which would be until the user either records something, cancels, or you timeout their action in the AutoResetEvent.

#### Return a `Task<string>` from your `SpeechToTextAsync` method:

```
public interface ISpeechToText
{
    Task<string> SpeechToTextAsync();
}
```

#### Add an `AutoResetEvent` to *pause* execution:

Note: Wrapping the `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne` to prevent hanging the application looper

```
public class SpeechToText_Android : Listener.ISpeechToText
{
    public static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    public static string SpeechText;
    const int VOICE = 10;

    public async Task<string> SpeechToTextAsync()
    {
        var voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
        voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
        voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPrompt, "Sprechen Sie jetzt");
        voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
        voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
        voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 15000);
        voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);
        voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, Java.Util.Locale.Default);

        SpeechText = "";
        autoEvent.Reset();
        ((Activity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(voiceIntent, VOICE);
        await Task.Run(() => { autoEvent.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)); });
        return SpeechText;
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity OnActivityResult:

```
    const int VOICE = 10;
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == VOICE)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                var matches = data.GetStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraResults);
                if (matches.Count != 0)
                {
                    var textInput = matches[0];
                    if (textInput.Length > 500)
                        textInput = textInput.Substring(0, 500);
                    SpeechToText_Android.SpeechText = textInput;
                }
            }
            SpeechToText_Android.autoEvent.Set();
        }
    }
```

Note: This is making use of a couple of static vars to simplify the implementation of this example... Some developers would say this is a code smell, I semi-agree, but you can not ever have more then one Google Speech Recognizer running at a time....

#### Hello World Example:

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        var speechTextLabel = new Label
        {
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            Text = "Waiting for text"
        };

        var speechButton = new Button();
        speechButton.Text = "Fetch Speech To Text Results";
        speechButton.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            var speechText = await WaitForSpeechToText();
            speechTextLabel.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(speechText) ? "Nothing Recorded" : speechText;
        };

        var content = new ContentPage
        {
            Title = "Speech",
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                    new Label {
                        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                        Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                    },
                    speechButton,
                    speechTextLabel
                }
            }
        };
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
    }

    async Task<string> WaitForSpeechToText()
    {
        return await DependencyService.Get<Listener.ISpeechToText>().SpeechToTextAsync();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @SushiHangover ! It works like a charm. If i get it right then you created a thread (autoEvent) which waits max 2 min. It blocks the return of the function. Then you are signaling the thread via "autoEvent.Set()" to continue after you got the input of the speech, Do I get it right?

Comment: @user3769192 That is exactly correct, this method works but it is not perfect.... You could timeout and when you do you have no way of cancelling the Google Recognizer. The "*right*" way would be to create a `SpeechRecognizer` (via `SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer`), build your own user interface, set a `RecognitionListener` as your callback and thus handle any words that are sent to your listener while in another thread have the ability to cancel/stop the recognizer, after a timeout period or the user cancels, and then tear-down your custom UI....

Comment: i tried the way of creating my own interface with SpeechRecognizer but i think i failed hard. So i decided to go back to the standard implementation. Thanks for the explanation and for you help !

Comment: @SushiHangover can I contact you somehow for a follow-up question to this topic?