# Xamarin For Loop won't wait for onActvitityResult

Tags: android, for-loop, android-intent, xamarin

I am creating something similar to a voice recognition accuracy game and I am using a for loop with the words I need to be name but the problem is after starting activity for result it just keeps running to the next word without giving you a chance to answer. I've seen possible alternatives of having two methods one being a callback class(never done something like this) and somehow having them relay to each other, but I'm not sure of how this works and can't find a detailed explanation. Here's my method with the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < vocabWords.Length; i++)
        {
            WordToGuess.Text = vocabWords[i];
                CurrWord = vocabWords[i];
            textBox.Text = "";
            string messageSpeakNow = "Speak";
            var voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPrompt, messageSpeakNow);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 15000);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);
            voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, Java.Util.Locale.Default);
            StartActivityForResult(voiceIntent, VOICE);
        }
```

Then I have my onactivityresult ,which I want the for loop to wait for, but instead it just keeps on repopping up with the google microphone over and over and then stops once the loop is done never giving the user a chance to answer
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultVal, Intent data)
        {

```
            if (requestCode == VOICE)
            {
                if (resultVal == Result.Ok)
                {
                    var matches = data.GetStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraResults);
                    if (matches.Count != 0)
                    {
                        bool saidIt = false;
                        while (!saidIt)
                        {
                            string textInput = textBox.Text + matches[0];
                            textBox.Text = textInput;
                            //set alert for executing the task
                            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                            alert.SetTitle("Is " + textBox.Text + ", what you said?");

                            alert.SetPositiveButton("Yes", (senderAlert, args) =>
                            {
                                noResponse = false;
                                saidIt = true;
                                SetResult(Result.Ok);
                            //change value write your own set of instructions
                            //you can also create an event for the same in xamarin
                            //instead of writing things here
                            if (textBox.Text == CurrWord)
                                {
                                    guess(1);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    guess(0);
                                }
                            });

                            alert.SetNegativeButton("No", (senderAlert, args) =>
                            {
                            //perform your own task for this conditional button click
                        });
                            //run the alert in UI thread to display in the screen
                            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                            {
                                alert.Show();
                            });

                        }
                    }
                    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultVal, data);
                }
            }


    }
```

Comment: Take a look at this for one approach : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614131/android-speech-recognition-pass-data-back-to-xamarin-forms/40616041#40616041

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StartActivityForResult doesn't wait for the result so you can't use it in a loop. You'll have to do something like call StartActivityForResult for the first word, then when you get the result in OnActivityResult see whether you've finished getting all the words (using some class variables for index and vocabWord) and if you haven't then call StartActivityForResult for the next word and so on until you've finished.