# Xamarin.Forms TextToSpeech

Tags: c#, android, interface, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to develop a mobile app with a SpeechToText feature, I found an example here [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614131/android-speech-recognition-pass-data-back-to-xamarin-forms) and i tried to follow its steps, but when i run the application and i tap on the button to record, i get a message saying "Unhandled Exception occurr, No body on method..".
I tried to debug and what I get is that its something related to the `DependecyService` running the `SpeechToTextAsync` method from the `ISpeecehToText` interface. 
Now I dont use interfaces too much so i'm a bit stuck understanding what is causing this error and how to solve it.

```
namespace LiveScoring {
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage {
    public MainPage() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void RecordBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
        WaitForSpeechToText();
    }

    private async void WaitForSpeechToText() {
        Output_lbl.Text = await DependencyService.Get<ISpeechToText>().SpeechToTextAsync();
     >> here I get the error     
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LiveScoring {
    public interface ISpeechToText {
        Task<string> SpeechToTextAsync();
    } 
}
```

---

```
namespace LiveScoring.Droid {
    public class SpeechToText : ISpeechToText {
        private const int VOICE = 10;
        public static string SpeechText;
        public static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        public SpeechToText() { }

        public async Task<string> SpeechToTextAsync() {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

            try {
                var voiceIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm);
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraPrompt, "Talk now");
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 15000);
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);
                voiceIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, Java.Util.Locale.Default);

                SpeechText = "";
                autoEvent.Reset();


                try {
                    ((Activity)Forms.Context).StartActivityForResult(voiceIntent, VOICE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                    tcs.SetResult("Device doesn't support speech to text");
                }

                await Task.Run(() => { autoEvent.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0)); });
                return SpeechText;

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                tcs.SetException(ex);
            }     

            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code in your Interface?

Comment: Done, edited with interface definition.

Comment: Thanks, the interface looks fine, so the issue must be in the class that implements the interface in your Android project. Can you post the code of that too?

Comment: Sure, here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this above your `namespace LiveScoring.Droid {` line, ie:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SpeechToText))]
namespace LiveScoring.Droid {
...
}
```

This way it will register the dependency service, so it will be called when you use the `DependencyService.Get<>()` method.

Comment: That was a good guess, it solved that issue, now it gives another exception: "there was no activity to handle the intent", maybe thats cause it says that `Forms.Context` is deprecated and I "should use a local context instead" ?

Comment: Most likely, I still haven't updated my Xamarin.Forms app, so I am still using Forms.Context everywhere.. I'll see if I can find out the proper way to get the context.

Comment: no problem, also I found this Nuget package, which gets the current Activity: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CurrentActivity. Try adding it to your Droid project, and see if it works. EDIT: actually this might be simpler: `Android.App.Application.Context` instead of `Forms.Context`

Comment: I tried to change Forms.Context to `((Activity)Android.App.Application.Context).StartActivityForResult(voiceIntent, VOICE);`
But i get an exception saying: "Cannot convert [..hash stuff].MainApplication to Android.App.Activity"

Comment: Ok, I just found this which should solve the issue.. https://www.davidbritch.com/2017/11/xamarinforms-25-and-local-context-on.html?m=1

Comment: Mh.. i tried both ways suggested on the linked post, but the Context seems to be always null. :\