# How to use async/await with an SDK that expects call-back based asynchronous activity

Tags: asynchronous, xamarin, xamarin.android, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am implementing native Android Facebook authentication in Xamarin Forms and am struggling with the Facebook SDK breaking my await/async chain. The SDK requires passing implementations of `IFacebookCallback` and `GraphRequest.IGraphJSONObjectCallback` which define callbacks to process results. I would like to do the following in code that requests a login:

```
public async Task LogInFacebookAsync()
{
    var loginResult = await _facebookManager.Login();  
    // do stuff with result
}
```

However, here's what I'm currently doing.
Code that requests a login:

```
public void LogInFacebookAsync()
{
    _facebookManager.Login(onFacebookLoginComplete);
}
private async Task<string> onFacebookLoginComplete(FacebookUser fbUser, string errorMessage) 
{
    // do stuff with result
}
```

Here is my FacebookManager class which implements the necessary interfaces. Notice that results can come from multiple callback methods: `OnCancel()`, `OnError()`, `OnCompleted()`, each of which invokes _onLoginComplete as passed in by the code above.

```
public class FacebookManager : Java.Lang.Object, IFacebookManager, IFacebookCallback, GraphRequest.IGraphJSONObjectCallback
{
    public Func<FacebookUser, string, Task> _onLoginComplete;
    public ICallbackManager _callbackManager;
    private Activity _context;

    public FacebookManager()
    {
        this._context = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
        _callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();
        LoginManager.Instance.RegisterCallback(_callbackManager, this);
    }

    public async Task Login(Func<FacebookUser, string, Task> onLoginComplete)
    {
        _onLoginComplete = onLoginComplete;
        LoginManager.Instance.SetLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NativeWithFallback);
        LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(_context, new List<string> { "public_profile", "email" });
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    #region IFacebookCallback   
    public void OnCancel()
    {
        _onLoginComplete?.Invoke(null, "Canceled!");
    }
    public void OnError(FacebookException error)
    {
        _onLoginComplete?.Invoke(null, error.Message);
    }       
    public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
    {
        var n = result as LoginResult;
        if (n != null)
        {
            var request = GraphRequest.NewMeRequest(n.AccessToken, this);
            var bundle = new Android.OS.Bundle();
            bundle.PutString("fields", "id, first_name, email, last_name, picture.width(500).height(500)");
            request.Parameters = bundle;
            request.ExecuteAsync();
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region GraphRequest.IGraphJSONObjectCallback
    public void OnCompleted(JSONObject p0, GraphResponse p1)
    {       
        // extract user
        _onLoginComplete?.Invoke(fbUser, string.Empty);   
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Is there any way I can wrap these operations so that I am "async all the way down"?

#### Update:

Thank you Paulo for the [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50783373/3165621). I was already thinking along those lines and you really crystallized the solution. My only concern with the answer was about it being thread-safe. What if a button is double-clicked or two API calls are made at the same time that require Facebook login? The following is my attempt to make the `LoginAsync()` method safer. However, I'm no expert at thread safety and I welcome all criticism.

```
private TaskCompletionSource<FacebookUser> _loginTcs;
public async Task<FacebookUser> LoginAsync()
{
    Task<FacebookUser> loginTask = _loginTcs?.Task;
    // Don't want to create a new login request to the Facebook API if one is already being made.
    if (loginTask != null && (loginTask.Status == TaskStatus.Running || loginTask.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation 
        || loginTask.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingToRun || loginTask.Status == TaskStatus.WaitingForChildrenToComplete))
    {
        return await loginTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    this._loginTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<FacebookUser>();
    LoginManager.Instance.SetLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NativeWithFallback);
    LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(_context, new List<string> { "public_profile", "email" });
    var user = await this._loginTcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    return user;
}
```

Comment: You can setup an `AutoResetEvent` and perform the waitone with an awaited `Task.Run` to avoid blocking the main thread, something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40616041/4984832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd449174). No need for anything else.

I don't know a lot about that API (and I'm surprised Xamarin does not provide na idiomatic .NET version of it) but, roughly, what you need to do is:

Add a task completion source to your class instead of the `_onLoginComplete` delegate:

```
// public Func<FacebookUser, string, Task> _onLoginComplete;
private TaskCompletionSource<FacebookUser> completion;
```

Change your `OnCancel` method to cancel the task:

```
public void OnCancel()
{
    this.completion.TrySetCanceled();
}
```

Change your `OnError` method to complete the task with error:

```
public void OnError(FacebookException error)
{
    this.completion.TrySetException(error);
}
```

Change your `OnCompleted` to set the task result:

```
public void OnCompleted(JSONObject p0, GraphResponse p1)
{       
    // extract user
    this.completion.TrySetResult(fbUser);   
}
```

Change your login method to create the task completion source and return the task completion source's task:

```
public async Task<FacebookUser> LoginAsync()
{
    this.completion = new TaskCompletionSource<FacebookUser>();
    LoginManager.Instance.SetLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NativeWithFallback);
    LoginManager.Instance.LogInWithReadPermissions(_context, new List<string> { "public_profile", "email" });
    await this.completion.Task;
}
```

Comment: To elaborate a little more [see converting older APM methods](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/06/27/using-tasks-to-implement-the-apm-pattern/)

Comment: Thank you, this is an excellent answer! Would you mind looking at the edit to my question? I tried to enhance the implementation to be thread safe, but I'm no expert on thread safety.