# How to implement Xamarin Speech Recognition

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new in xamarin, and I was wondering if it is possible to implement this kind of speech recognition:

First the user inputs "Hello" but the text output will be "Hi"?

I have found this link: [Android speech recognition pass data back to Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40614131/android-speech-recognition-pass-data-back-to-xamarin-forms)

but it only outputs the speech "Hello" as a text "Hello".

Comment: could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Speech recognition usually involves translating what you say into text.If you need to change its content, perhaps you can try to make some judgments directly after the transformation and make changes according to your requirements like change the result in the link above :

in **MainActivity OnActivityResult**:

```
    const int VOICE = 10;
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == VOICE)
        {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                var matches = data.GetStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraResults);
                if (matches.Count != 0)
                {
                    var textInput = matches[0];
                    if (textInput.Length > 500)
                        textInput = textInput.Substring(0, 500);

                    //make a judgment and change the value
                    if(textInput.Eques("hello")){
                        textInput = "Hi";
                    }
                    SpeechToText_Android.SpeechText = textInput;
                }
            }
            SpeechToText_Android.autoEvent.Set();
        }
    }
```